# Table column hidden in Safari when using css style for width that contains a percentage for a col element within a table's colgroup

Tags: html, css

Here is a [link](https://jsfiddle.net/mritzman/oq256gsc/) to a jsfiddle that works in the modern browsers I tested (Chrome, Firefox and IE11) except for Safari.  It seems that Safari does not support adding a calc style containing a percentage to a col element within a table's colgroup.  Below is a code excerpt from the jsfiddle, the col element with id "col1" has a width style of "calc(100% - 70px)".  On Safari the Month column is hidden whereas on other modern browsers such as Chrome, Firefox and IE11 it is visible.  If we remove this style then things behave as expected on Safari where the Month column takes up all the available width and the Savings column stays a static 70px width.  Note that the box-sizing for all elements is border-box which is specified in the css.

```
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col id="col1" style="width: calc(100% - 70px)" />
    <col id="col2" style="width: 70px" />
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100.58</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80.67</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the related CSS:

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  border-color: #dbdcde;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

th {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: larger;
  background-color: #dbdcde;
  border: 0.1rem solid #aaa;
}

tr {
  border: 0.1rem solid #dbdcde;
  color: #000000;
}

td {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `width: calc(100% - 70px)` as this cant be done by CSS as it doesnt support calculations in general and no percentage minus pixel in specific. 
Just leave this out (don't set any width) and keep setting the other column to 70px.

This will make second column 70px and the first will be screen width - 70px just as you wanted